# Changing background color of cursor during selection

Tags: syntax-highlighting, terminal

Coming from Sublime, I find the following behaviour frustrating.

[image]

When I select some text, the first (or last depending upon which way you select) character flashes between the text color and your background color (in my case, black). So it gives the impression that only the '4' characters are selected.

Is there anyway to change the background color of your current cursor position when text is highlighted, so I can blend it into the selection when it flashes?

I'm using gnome terminal, on ubuntu.

Comment: This is just the `Cursor` highlight group. There is no differentiation between when there is a visual selection or not. I think your only option is to change what color your cursor is.

Comment: Or you could stop the cursor from blinking altogether. [Instructions here](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Terminal/FAQ?action=show&redirect=Terminal%2FFAQ#How_can_I_change_a_profile_setting_from_the_command_line.3F).